# How can I get a commit message from a bzr post-commit hook?

Tags: python, dvcs, bazaar

I'm trying to write a `bzr post-commit` hook for my private bugtracker, but I'm stuck at the function signature of

```
post_commit(local, master, old_revno, old_revid, new_revno, mew_revid)
```

How can I extract the commit message for the branch from this with `bzrlib` in `Python`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the answer is like so:

```
def check_commit_msg(local, master, old_revno, old_revid, new_revno, new_revid):
    branch = local or master
    revision = branch.repository.get_revision(new_revid)
    print revision.message
```

local and master are Branch objects, so once you have a revision, it's easy to extract the message.